# @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler not getting triggered for my RestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

In order to have unified exception handling throughout the application I am using [Error Handling for REST with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) solution#3 which uses `@ControllerAdvice` along with `@ExceptionHandler`.

Spring version: 4.3.22.RELEASE

Spring Boot version: 1.5.19.RELEASE

This is a Spring boot application and following is my package structure.

```
src/main/java
  com.test.app.controller
     MyRestController.java       -- This is my Rest controller
  com.test.app.handler
     RestExceptionHandler.java   -- This is my ControllerAdvice class
```

Following is my ControllerAdvice code and one of the Controller throws `InvalidDataException` but still the corresponding `@ExceptionHandler` is not called. Instead I am getting `Unexpected 'e'` as the response body with *http 400*.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidDataException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody ErrorResponse handleValidationError(final InvalidDataException ex,
                                                             final WebRequest request) {
        log.error("InvalidDataException message:{} ", ex.getMessage());
        return getExceptionResponse("Failed with Invalid data" + ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }


    private ErrorResponse getExceptionResponse(final String message, final Integer errorCode) {
        final ErrorResponse exceptionResponse = new ErrorResponse();
        exceptionResponse.setErrorCode(errorCode.toString());
        exceptionResponse.setErrorDescription(message);
        log.error("message:{}", exceptionResponse);
        return exceptionResponse;
    }
}
```

I looked at other post on SO as well as other forums where they mentioned to use `@EnableWebMvc` and `@ComponentScan` etc. but nothing helped. Could someone please help me understand what am I missing?

Following is my `Controller` and corresponding interface.

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController implements MyApi {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<MyResponse>> myGet(@RequestHeader(value = "a") String a,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "b") String b,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "c") String c,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "d") String d,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "e") String e,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "f") String f,
                                                               @RequestHeader(value = "g") String g) {

      List<MyResponse> responses = service.getData(c, d, e, f); // This throws exception
      return new ResponseEntity<>(responses, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}


@Validated
@Api(value = "My", description = "the My API")
//This is generated interface through swagger codegen
public interface MyApi {

    @ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "myGet", notes = "", response = MyResponse.class, responseContainer = "List")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "normal response", response = MyResponse.class, responseContainer = "List"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Request is invalid", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error", response = ErrorResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 503, message = "Service Unavailable", response = ErrorResponse.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/test",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<List<MyResponse>> myGet(@ApiParam(value = "a" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="a", required=true) String a,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "b" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="b", required=true) String b,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "c" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="c", required=true) String c,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "d" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="d", required=true) String d,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "e" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="e", required=true) String e,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "f" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="f", required=true) String f,
                                                   @ApiParam(value = "g" ,required=true) @RequestHeader(value="g", required=true) String g) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", "{  \"aNum\" : 0,  \"cNum\" : \"cNum\"}");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

Following is the code snippet from my `GlobalExceptionHandler`

```
class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver, Ordered, InitializingBean {
    ...
    @Override
    protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception) {
        if (exception instanceof com.myframework.SystemException) {
            return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(this, exceptionMethods.get(com.myframework.SystemException.class.getName()));
        } else if (exception instanceof GenericApplicationException) {
            return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(this, exceptionMethods.get(com.myframework.GenericApplicationException.class.getName()));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of your MyRestController.

Comment: @mentallurg I have added the Controller code in the question, pls take a look.

Comment: 'Instead I am getting Unexpected 'e' as the' - do this appear in the console in a stack trace? If so, please, paste that stack trace in the question as well

Comment: I get `Unexpected 'e'` in the response body with HTTP code 400. There is no exception trace in the Console

Comment: So what would you expect instead? Seems like your error handler is working fine. "Unexpected 'e' " is the exception message coming from your service, it is returned with http400 instead of http500 for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: If you don't see an error log, maybe your logging configuration is wrong.

Comment: also you should show the URL you use when you get the error, and possibly the parts of your main application config where you include both the controller and the ControllerAdvice

Comment: what exception is code throwing and what does the stacktrace look like?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I get Unexpected 'e' in the response body with HTTP code 400. There is no exception trace in the Console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should work. Some possible causes that make it fails may be :

1. The `RestExceptionHandler` is not declared as a spring bean yet ?  `@SpringBootApplication` by default will only scan the spring beans to register under its package and all of its sub-packages.
2. The controller is actually not throwing `InvalidDataException` but other exception ?

Anyway I suggest you to make the following changes to check if `RestExceptionHandler` is get called .

In your spring boot main application class , explicitly register `RestExceptionHandler` as a spring bean using `@Import`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(RestExceptionHandler.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Also in the `RestExceptionHandler` , also include a method to catch the most generic Exception :

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ErrorResponse handleGenericException(final Exception ex ,final WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("handleGenericException ....");
        return getExceptionResponse("Failed with Invalid data" + ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
}
```

Please let me know if the `RestExceptionHandler` will get called after making these changes.

Comment: Sure will try and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Ken, Thanks for your answer. As we are using an in-house framework I believe that is interfering with the error handling, and I see that following class from the framework gets called
`class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver, Ordered, InitializingBean {}`  and following method from that class gets called:
`@Override
    protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception) {..}`

Comment: Yes , I guess most probably it is interfering , for example your customised `GlobalExceptionHandler` may be configured to have higher priority to resolve he exception than the built-in one and it somehow cannot handle `@ControllerAdvice`....

Comment: I did give `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` on my RestExceptionHandler  but even then it does not get called. How to have it call my handler?

Comment: Your customised GlobalExceptionHandler are overriding `getExceptionHandlerMethod()` which contain the logic of how to call the `@ControllerAdvice` bean. I am guessing are you override the logic about getting `@ControllerAdvice` ? As you do not show more codes about how to configure the exception handlers and what the `GlobalExceptionHandler` looks like , I can only guess ...

Comment: I added the code snippet from my `GlobalExceptionHandler` in the question above, please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my above comment?

Comment: Not sure why you override `getExceptionHandlerMethod()` in `GlobalExceptionHandler` as you are override the logic to call @ControllerAdvice bean. Can you remove them to see if your  @ControllerAdvice get called ?

Comment: Or change the  `return null` to `return super.getExceptionHandlerMethod( handlerMethod,  exception) `

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have no other spring components that extend

```
AbstractErrorController
```

Comment: I don't have that anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

below code was enough for me to make the Adviser class workable in the Controller class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(RestExceptionHandler.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below controller advice should solve the problem.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

 @ExceptionHandler(value = {InvalidDataException.class})
 protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidDataException(
  RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(getExceptionResponse("Failed with Invalid data" + ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Here's a demo project of Global Error Handler in Spring Boot https://github.com/s2agrahari/global-excpetion-handler-spring-boot

Comment: Don't think it needs to extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` . I have use many `@ControllerAdvice` without extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in many projects and work very well..

Comment: Thanks @KenChan for reporting. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

replace `@ControllerAdvice` with `@RestControllerAdvice`